# Can I disable JS in a UIWebView? (Objective C)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm writing a simple RSS reader for iOS using Xcode 8 and building for iOS 10.0.

I allow the user to save webpages for offline reading; however, when there is no internet connection, local HTML files take a long time to load as the UIWebView I'm loading them with tries to resolve external assets like images etc (or at least, that's what I think it's doing). I figured disabling JS when an internet connection is not present would solve this problem, but I don't know how to do that and I haven't found much information on the matter.

tl,dr: is there a way to disable javascript in a UIWebView?

Thank you

Comment: Update: by using a WKWebView as [LGP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835813/can-i-disable-js-in-a-uiwebview-objective-c/48838725#48838725) recommended the speed problems have vanished, so I don't need to disable js after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are building for iOS 10.0 you should use `WKWebView` instead. It has support for disabling javascript, and is also the recommended component to use.

First create the preferences object. You need to set this up before the web view is created.

```
WKPreferences *preferences = [[WKPreferences alloc] init];
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = NO; // Here its set

// Other things you might want to disable
preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = NO;
```

Then create the configuration object which holds the preferences.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.preferences = preferences;
```

Then create your web view.

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:configuration];
```

[Read more about WKWebView here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. Just out of curiosity, was there any way to do it with the old UIWebView?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of.

Comment: Actually the WKWebView doesn't recognize the javaScriptEnabled attribute for some reason, am I doing it wrong? I followed this guide to set it up: https://iostpoint.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/implement-wkwebview-in-ios/

Comment: Well either way the problem I had is solved (see the comment on my op) so it doesn't matter too much other than for the sake of learning. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry about that! I was too quick. The property is available, but on a preference object you set on the configuration. Note that you should use the initializer that takes the configuration parameter, or it won't work. I have updated the answer.